# Equivalent of Configure<T> using autofac modules

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

What is the equivalent to the method `Configure<TOptions>` of the `OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions` when using Autofac modules?

My ConfigureServices method looks like this, but I want to move the `services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"))` to MyModule.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));

    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.Populate(services);
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule<MyModule>();

    var container = containerBuilder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

How does the registration look like in the Load-method of the Module

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    // configure options here
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Autofac personally, but generally speaking, all `Configure<T>` does is 1) bind a particular configuration section to a class and 2) register that class with the service collection, so it can be injected directly.

As a result, you can instead use the following to bind your strongly-typed configuration:

```
var config = config.GetSection("MyOptions").Get<MyOptions>();
```

And, then you'd simply register that with Autofac as a constant in singleton-scope.

Comment: You are correct: `builder.Register(p => configuration.GetSection("MyOptions").Get<MyOptions>()).SingleInstance();`

Answer (score 10):

I recently encountered this same issue, I implemented the following so that you can still use IOptions, IOptionsMonitor and IOptionsSnapshot, but register the configuration from the AutoFac Module.

The prerequisite is that you call `services.AddOptions()` in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
var sfConfig = _configuration.GetSection("MyOptions");

builder.Register(ctx => new ConfigurationChangeTokenSource<MyOptions>(Options.DefaultName, sfConfig))
       .As<IOptionsChangeTokenSource<MyOptions>>()
       .SingleInstance();

builder.Register(ctx => new NamedConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<MyOptions>(Options.DefaultName, sfConfig, _ => { }))
       .As<IConfigureOptions<MyOptions>>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

This requires that you run services.AddOptions() within the ConfigureServices method.

In the example above, "MyOptions" is the section name in your configuration, and `MyOptions` type is the POCO class that has the fields to hold the result.

This is basically a conversion of what microsoft has here: https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: I'm slightly unsure about the provided example. The way I read it is from ConfigureService, call Services.AddOptions() without parameters, and the builder.Register calls inside of the module. Where I'm lost, is where _configuration is declared in relation to the Module. Could you update your example to a full minimal example, reflecting the format of the example methods from the original post?

Comment: Utilize the RegisterModule method overload that accepts a constructed module with parameters. Ie: containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new MyModule(Configuration));

Comment: Configuration would be instantiated from within the asp.net core startup, IConfiguration can be injected into Startup class after configured in program.cs, examples found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#access-configuration-in-startup

Answer (score 0):

Startup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // Register your own things directly with Autofac here. Don't
            // call builder.Populate(), that happens in AutofacServiceProviderFactory
            // for you.
            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule(Configuration));
        }
```

AutofacModule.cs

```
 public class AutofacModule: Module
    {
        private IConfiguration configuration;

        public AutofacModule(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Register(p => configuration.GetSection("AppAPIKey").Get<ConfigSettings>()).SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<TestService>()
                .As<ITestService>()
                .SingleInstance();
        }
    }
```